# ¿Como actualizar un RecyclerView sin que la lista reinicie?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Lo único que hago es meter un nuevo array con los nuevos elementos que traigo desde la Api con este método en el adaptador

```
public void setData(ArrayList<Receta> recetas){
    this.recetas.addAll(recetas);}
```

En el fragment lo que hago es comprobar si ya existe un adaptador si este existe le meto los nuevos datos con el metodo de arriba.

```
 if(recetasAdapter == null){
                recetasAdapter = new RecetasAdapter(recetas);
            }else{

                recetasAdapter.setData(recetas);
            }
```

Y en el PostExecute le meto el nuevo adaptador en el recyclerView

```
rvExplorarRecetas.setAdapter(s);
```

El problema de esto es que yo al meter nuevos elementos al array este se vuelve al principio y lo que quiero es que se mantenga en la ultima pósición antes de cargar los nuevos datos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes llamar a este método tras actualizar los datos

```
recetasAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```